# $U(n)$ is not isomorphic to $SU(n) \times S^1$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, unitary-matrices

I managed to prove this after looking at proofs that $O(n)$ is not isomorphic to $SO(n) \times \pm I$ for n even by showing that the centres are of a different size.

$Z(U) = Z(SU) = λI$ but $Z(SU(n) \times S^1) = λI \times [0,2π)$.
Therefore $Z(U) \subset Z(SU(n) \times S^1)$ and hence not isomorphic.

Thing is, we never discussed the centres of these groups and it seems a bit weird for a linear algebra class to have a question with a proof like that. Is there any other more linear algebra-y way to prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is more natural to use the determinant, see the duplicate. There the same doubt was mentioned, that the proof with centers is not so "insightful". On the other hand, the definition of a *center* is easy and it should be possible to compute the center.